# Google Site Navigation Buttons Using URLs Stored in a Google Sheet

Tags: button, google-sheets, google-sites

I am trying to add `BACK` and `NEXT` navigation buttons to my Google site.
However, I want the URLs that are associated with the `BACK` and `NEXT` buttons to come from a Google Sheet.
In other words, I want the `BACK` and `NEXT` buttons in the Google site to get their URLs from specific cells in a Google Sheet.
If this can be achieved, I can dynamically change the URLs for the `BACK` and `NEXT` buttons in the Google Sheet, based on answers to questions posed in previous pages of the Google Site.
Here's a simplified flow diagram.

[image: Here's a simplified flow diagram.]

If this cannot be achieve using Google Site's native button component, can someone offer another way of doing this and still use the Google Sheet as a reference for the URLs?
Perhaps by using Google Site's `<EMBED>` option, where I can embed two buttons, `BACK` and `NEXT` and their URLs are still pulled from a specified Google Sheet.
Thank You Kindly, in advance, for your very valuable guidance.